# How to direct to a folder and access Excel files

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Folder called "Raw Data" and have several excel file name with the extension .xlsx 
I have another Excel file with enabled macros as "Test.xlsm".

Right now, I have an macro, working in such a way that, it goes to the local directory and then opens the excel files. This is not feasible for me when I change my folder.

Is it possible, I can have a code, in such a way that, it just looks for the folder "Raw Data". and opens the files I mention.

I have no idea on how to do this. Any lead would be helpful .

Right now I have the below code working. (But this looks for the raw data from a drive location D")

```
Private Sub CommandButton11_Click()
Dim filename As String

Workbooks.Open ("D:\Jenny\Raw data\Result.xlsx")

filename = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Result.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Comment: What do you mean by "looks for the folder"? Do you not *know* where the folder is?

Comment: If you want the macro to allow you to browse to the folder, use the `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)`

Comment: You would not create something that looked for `\raw data` *anywhere*, that could take ages and would be very inefficient.  You need a clue as to where it is, for example in a know path like the users documents or app data folder or somewhere in relation to ActiveWorkbook.Path - for example a subdirectory of it.

Comment: You could set a CONST to the directory and use the const. If you want to loop through all of the .xlsx files check out the DIR command.

Comment: @DavidZemens I know where the folder is. But I want to avoid the using the directory. For eg, if I am sending the whole file to someone, My xlsm and Raw data folder, he should also be able to use the xlsm. because I have it in such a way that, when you click a button in the xlsm file, the required xlsx opens.

Comment: Just use the folder picker to prompt the user to locate the Raw Data folder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user knows where the folder is, just prompt for input:

```
Dim fldr$
Dim fdlg As FileDialog
Set fdlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
fdlg.Show

If fdlg.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
    fldr = fdlg.SelectedItems(1)
Else: 
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim wb as Workbook
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fldr & Application.PathSeparator & "Results.xlsx")
```

Of course you should have error-handling in case the file doesn't exist in the folder the user selected, etc.

Or use the `Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)` to prompt the user to *locate* the files manually. The application can't otherwise know where the files might exist -- they could be literally *anywhere*, or they might not even exist in a location that the user can access.

```
Dim resultsBook as Workbook
Dim testBook as Workbook
Dim fdlg as FileDialog
Set fdlg = Application.FileDialg(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
MsgBOx "Select the Results file"
fdlg.Show
If fdlg.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
    Set resultsBook = Workbooks.Open(fdlg.SelectedItems(1))
Else:
    Exit Sub
End If
MsgBox "Select the Test file"
fdlg.Show
    If fdlg.SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
    Set testBook = Workbooks.Open(fdlg.SelectedItems(1))
Else:
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternate method using `CreateObject("Shell.Application")`

```
Sub tst()

    Dim oShell As Object
    Dim sFolderPath As String

    Set oShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder", 0)
    If oShell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub  'Pressed cancel

    sFolderPath = oShell.Self.Path & Application.PathSeparator

    MsgBox sFolderPath
    'Workbooks.Open sFolderPath & "Result.xlsx"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the ability to rename and possibly move the Raw Data folder and not "break" the macro. If that's the case, save the Test.xlsm file in the Raw Data folder.

Then do something like this loop to open & process each XLSX raw data file in the folder. My code it's userFiles / yours may be rawDataFiles or something.

```
userFilesPath = ThisWorkbook.Path
userFileName = Dir(userFilesPath & "*.xlsx", vbNormal)

Do While userFileName <> ""
    On Error Resume Next
    userFile = userFilesPath & userFileName

    ' this is the raw data file
    On Error Resume Next
    Set uf = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=userFile, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)

    ' do some stuff with the raw data
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each s In uf.Sheets
        If Len(s.Range("a1").Value) > 1 Then
            s.Range("a1:z" & s.Range("a1000000").End(xlUp).Row).Copy
            ws.Range("a" & ws.Range("a1000000").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        End If
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Next
    uf.Close False

    userFileName = Dir
Loop
```

Comment: could you please comment what we are doing with this code ?

Comment: your code is suiting my requirement.Could you please help me with avoiding the  errors?